# Entity Framework Linq - how to get groups that contain all your data

Tags: linq, entity-framework, group-by

Here a sample dataset:

`OrderProduct` is a table that contains the productIds that were part of a given order.
**Note**: *OrderProduct is a database table and I am using EF.*

OrderId, ProductId

1, 1

2, 2

3, 4

3, 5

4, 5

4, 2

5, 2

5, 3

What I want to be able to do is find an order that contains **only** the productIds that I am searching for. So if my input was productIds 2,3, then I should get back OrderId 5.

I know how I can group data, but I am unsure of how to perform the select on the group.

Here is what I have:

```
var q = from op in OrderProduct
group op by op.OrderId into orderGroup
select orderGroup;
```

Not sure how to proceed from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<int> products = new List<int> {2, 3};

IEnumerable<OrderProduct> orderProducts = new List<OrderProduct>
{
   new OrderProduct(1, 1), 
   new OrderProduct(2, 2), 
   new OrderProduct(3, 4), 
   new OrderProduct(3, 5), 
   new OrderProduct(4, 5), 
   new OrderProduct(4, 2), 
   new OrderProduct(5, 2), 
   new OrderProduct(5, 3),
};

var orders =
   (from op in orderProducts
    group op by op.OrderId into orderGroup
    //magic goes there
    where !products.Except(orderGroup.Select(x => x.ProductId)).Any()
    select orderGroup);

//outputs 5
orders.Select(x => x.Key).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Or you can have another version as pointed in another answer, just replace

```
 where !products.Except(orderGroup.Select(x => x.ProductId)).Any()
```

on

```
 where products.All(pid => orderGroup.Any(op => op.ProductId == pid))
```

second one will have ~ 15% better performance (I've checked that)

**Edit**

According to the last requirement change, that you need orders that contain not all productIds you are searching, but exactly those and only those productIds, I wrote an updated version:

```
 var orders =
       (from op in orderProducts
        group op by op.OrderId into orderGroup
        //this line was added
        where orderGroup.Count() == products.Count()
        where !products.Except(orderGroup.Select(x => x.ProductId)).Any()
        select orderGroup);
```

So the only thing you'll need is to add a precondition ensuring that collections contains the same amount of elements, it will work for **both** previous queries, and as a bonus I suggest **3rd** version of the most important where condition:

```
where orderGroup.Select(x => x.ProductId).Intersect(products).Count() == orderGroup.Count()
```

Comment: Restuta, this query has the same problem as dasblinkenlight's answer. The products.Except cant be used when using EF.

Comment: oh, I see, is it possible to load all OrderProducts and then do in-memory filtering? if no, then I would suggest to go with simple SQL here.

Comment: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx) states that both `All` and `Except` are supported. What exact error did you get?

Comment: As an example try productId = 2. It should return only OrderId = 2 (but it returns 2,4 and 5)

Comment: Restuta, I am sorry, you were right, I was using LinqPad and I was using LinqToSql. Your code does work using EF. (my bad!). Your first answer doesnt work correctly when you provide it only one productId (in which case I would want only the orders that contain just that one productId, instead it returns all orders that contained that product). As an example try productId = 2. It should return only OrderId = 2 (but it returns 2,4 and 5). I tried both your solutions (Except and All) and both have the same problem.

Comment: I've modified you question accordingly, sorry but you were asking for _order that contains all of the productIds_. I gave you exactly what you asked =). It's correct to say that `order` with product ids `2, 3` when you are looking for `2` contains _all of the product ids_ since [2, 3].Contains(2) is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, I'd try something like this:

```
var prodIds = new[] {2, 3};

from o in context.Orders
where prodIds.All(pid => o.OrderProducts.Any(op => op.ProductId == pid))
select o
```

In plain language: "get the orders that have a product with every ID in the given list."

#### Update

Since it appears you are using LINQ to SQL rather than LINQ to Entities, here's another approach:

```
var q = context.Orders;
foreach(var pid in prodIds)
{
    q = q.Where(o => o.OrderProducts.Any(op => op.ProductId == pid));
}
```

Rather than using a single LINQ statement, you essentially build the query piecemeal.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain the down-vote. As far as I can tell, this approach should do what was asked.

Comment: +1 I have no idea why anyone would downvote this: it looks like a working solution to me.

Comment: StriplingWarrior, this too has the "NotSupportedException: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator." problem. I think its because of the "ALL" clause.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using EF, cos message is saying that it's LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @Rajah: As Restuta points out, you claim to be using Entity Framework, but the error message you're reporting says it's LINQ to SQL. The two frameworks are different, and don't have all the same features. This answer is valid as it stands for Entity Framework, but a different approach is required for LINQ to SQL, since it doesn't support calling `.All` on an in-memory list.

Comment: I can confirm that this approach works well, i'm on Entity Framework 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to StriplingWarrior's answer I managed to figure this out. Not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it works.

```
List<int> prodIds = new List<int>{2,3};

var q = from o in Orders
//get all orderproducts that contain products in the ProdId list
where o.OrderProducts.All(op => prodIds.Contains(op.ProductId))
//now group the OrderProducts by the Orders
select from op in o.OrderProducts 
group op by op.OrderId into opGroup
//select only those groups that have the same count as the prodId list
where opGroup.Count() == prodIds.Count()
select opGroup;

//get rid of any groups that may be empty
q = q.Where(fi => fi.Count()> 0);
```

(I am using LinqPad, which is why the query looks a little funky - no context, etc)